# Why did the USA ever test nukes on their own soil?

Tags: united-states, nuclear-weapons, nuclear, 1950s

I've recently read about these atom bomb tests that frequently occurred semi-near Las Vegas, which people flocked to. Even if they didn't understand the risks at the time, isn't it a serious problem to blast some stretch of land repeatedly with huge explosions?

Didn't they *begin* the nuclear tests far away from home on some remote islands or something? Why ever bring it "home"? Why not keep making the tests far away? Why take the risk that maybe there is something unforeseen about the a-bombs?

Comment: The first experiments were in the Arizonan desert (Project Manhattan).

Comment: @gktscrk [New Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_(nuclear_test)), not Arizona.

Comment: @Spencer: Sorry, poor geography on my part. Should have said "desert around Los Alamos".

Comment: Testing a secret weapon you are still working on during the middle of a war on *someone else's* soil seems like it would be a foolhardy risk.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I wonder if they tried to do it in Canada or somewhere similar (Newfoundland was under essential US military occupation), but I think not just because the transport wouldn't have justified itself for the extra security risk.

Comment: 225 miles (current roads) from Los Alamos to the Trinity Site. Los Alamos sits up in the Jemez mountains outside of Santa Fe.

Comment: @T.E.D. Actually they did test the 2nd and 3rd weapons on someone else's soil...

Comment: @Maycol - because testing was a huge operation with massive logistic and it rapidly became clear that doing it in the middle of the Pacific was not going to work well. https://nationalatomictestingmuseum.org/ has some info.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík: If you are referring to Hiroshima and Nagasaki, that's grossly inaccurate - as it misses the important distinction between the two bomb designs for Uranium and Plutonium. The vastly simpler Uranium design was never tested until Hiroshima, while only the Plutonum design required a test (**Trinity**) prior to use at Nagasaki.

Comment: @JonCuster: that limk si for the home page. Do you have a more specific link?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - there is a lot to look through there, particularly the videos so I figured the top level was sufficient. It is a nice museum to visit, and I know several people who recovered what are now exhibits there from the Test Site. I still prefer driving around the Test Site, but not everyone can do that...

Comment: A little-known non-nuclear testing site was the Salton Sea, https://www.desertusa.com/salton-sea/salton-sea-test-base.html - lots of engineering tests there until that was moved to Tonopah, northwest of the Nevada Test Site.

Comment: @JonCuster:So all they apparently did at Salton Sea in 1944-45 was practice bombing runs with a parachute-delivered "*device*". Not very informative, or risky.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - post war, it was used until 1961 for a range of engineering tests until that operation was moved to Tonopah (partly to be close to the growing Test Site and the support that afforded). Nuclear testing isn't all big booms.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are not familiar with the US West?  Even today (and more so in the 1940s & 50s) there are places where you can be miles and miles (substitute km if desired) away from anything much other than sagebrush and rattlesnakes.  The tests were conducted in such locations.  (Note that Las Vegas wasn't much of a place in those days, either.)

OTOH, those "remote islands" were mostly populated.  When later H-bomb tests were conducted there, the military had to remove the populations from them, in addition to the logistical problems of transporting the bombs, monitoring equipment, and support staff.  See e.g. Bikini Atoll.

Comment: Did you know [not all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Shoal) the tests were down by Vegas?

Comment: @justCal: Yes, I'm quite well aware of that.  My point still holds: the places where the tests were held were a long way from anything, and in most cases still are.  Las Vegas only had a population of about 25,000 in 1950.